# Windows Admin Rights dialogue broken

Tags: windows, windows-10

whenever my Windows 10 needs Admin rights, I get this message:

[image]

Can anybody please tell me how to fix this?

Mebus

Comment: Where I have seen this , it was Symantec causing the issue. Do you have Symantec installed?

Comment: No, I have got Sophos installed :-P But I don't know how to uninstall it, because I need this dialog for it.

Comment: There are force uninstall instructions in this Sophos article. https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/109668 I hope this helps